# udevadm/persistent USB names not working (permission error)

Tags: linux, usb, symlink, rules, udev

I have 2 identical Bluetooth receivers attached to a Raspberry Pi that
I need to monitor Bluetooth signals at different parts of a room.
Unfortunately, the 2 devices have the same idVendor and idProduct so I
have resorted to using the ATTR{serial} in hopes udev could
distinguish between the two.

The issue is that after I created the udev rules (with new SYMLINK),
only 1 of the Bluetooth receivers shows a DEVLINK of the correct name
I provided in the rule. The other Bluetooth receiver DEVLINK name is
never shown. I have tried a number of things: rebooting, reload udev
rules, restarting udevadm. The console provides the following error
when in dm test (full outputs provided below- I think there
may be a permission issue per the latter part of this output?):

```
udev_event_execute_rules: no node name set, will use kernel supplied
name 'bus/usb/001/006'
udev_node_add: creating device node '/dev/bus/usb/001/006',
devnum=189:5, mode=01664, uid=0, gid=0
udev_node_mknod: preserve file '/dev/bus/usb/001/006', because it has
correct dev_t
udev_node_mknod: preserve permissions /dev/bus/usb/001/006, 021664, uid=0, gid=0
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/189:5' to
'../bus/usb/001/006'
udev_device_update_db: unable to create temporary db file
'/run/udev/data/c189:5.tmp': Permission denied
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/006
```

If it helps, here is what I did in order to create the rules and
execute the tests:

First, I ran udevadm info to identify differing attributes between the
2 receivers.
The idVendor, serial, and idProduct on 1 device were the following:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0a5c"
ATTR{serial}=="0002723FAE6C"
ATTR{idProduct}=="21e8"
```

And on the other device...

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0a5c"
ATTR{serial}=="5CF37067320A"
ATTR{idProduct}=="21e8"
```

I created a new rules file called "00-my-usb-device.rules" which looks
like the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0a5c",
ATTRS{serial}=="5CF37067320A", SYMLINK+="driverBT"
```

I then created a separate rules filed called "01-my-usb-device.rules"
(originally I had both rules in 1 file but wanted to try all
possibilities. This file looks like the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="USB", ATTR{serial}=="0002723FAE6C",
ATTR{idVendor}=="0a5c", SYMLINK+="rearBT"
```

Running devadm on the first port with serial num "5CF37067320A" (also
was the first rule that I set):
    udevadm test /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2
    run_command: calling: test
    adm_test: version 175
    This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program,
    specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
    some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

```
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/00-my-usb-device.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/01-my-usb-device.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-local-rpi.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/40-scratch.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/42-qemu-usb.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-fuse.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-gpsd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-i2c-tools.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-ifplugd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-2.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading
'/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules' as
rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules' as rules     file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-python-pifacecommon.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-python3-pifacecommon.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-triggerhappy.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/run/udev/rules.d/61-dev-root-link.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules' as rules file
add_rule: IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id', replacing
/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules:13
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/70-udev-acl.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules' as rules file
add_rule: IMPORT found builtin 'path_id', replacing
/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules:23
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-cd-aliases-generator.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading
'/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading
'/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/99-input.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules' as rules file
udev_rules_new: rules use 145392 bytes tokens (12116 * 12 bytes),
24358 bytes buffer
udev_rules_new: temporary index used 39920 bytes (1996 * 20 bytes)
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x18b5748 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x18b2258 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2'
udev_device_read_db: device 0x18b2258 filled with db file data
udev_rules_apply_to_event: LINK 'driverBT'
/etc/udev/rules.d/00-my-usb-device.rules:1
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x18b3188 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x18b3640 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x18b3ae8 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x18b3f88 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x18b42d8 has devpath         '/devices/platform'
udev_rules_apply_to_event: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id'
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-2.rules:11
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR=Broadcom_Corp
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Broadcom\x20Corp
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR_ID=0a5c
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL=BCM20702A0
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL_ENC=BCM20702A0
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL_ID=21e8
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_REVISION=0112
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_SERIAL=Broadcom_Corp_BCM20702A0_5CF37067320A
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=5CF37067320A
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_BUS=usb
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0101:ffffff:fe0101:
udev_rules_apply_to_event: MODE 0664 /lib/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules:36
udev_event_execute_rules: no node name set, will use kernel supplied
name 'bus/usb/001/009'
udev_node_add: creating device node '/dev/bus/usb/001/009',
devnum=189:8, mode=01664, uid=0, gid=0
udev_node_mknod: preserve file '/dev/bus/usb/001/009', because it has
correct dev_t
udev_node_mknod: preserve permissions /dev/bus/usb/001/009, 021664, uid=0,     gid=0
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/189:8' to
'../bus/usb/001/009'
link_find_prioritized: found 'c189:8' claiming '/run/udev/links/driverBT'
link_update: creating link '/dev/driverBT' to '/dev/bus/usb/001/009'
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/driverBT' to
'bus/usb/001/009'
udev_device_update_db: unable to create temporary db file
'/run/udev/data/c189:8.tmp': Permission denied
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVLINKS=/dev/driverBT
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/009
DEVNUM=009
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=BCM20702A0
ID_MODEL_ENC=BCM20702A0
ID_MODEL_ID=21e8
ID_REVISION=0112
ID_SERIAL=Broadcom_Corp_BCM20702A0_5CF37067320A
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=5CF37067320A
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0101:ffffff:fe0101:
ID_VENDOR=Broadcom_Corp
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Broadcom\x20Corp
ID_VENDOR_ID=0a5c
MAJOR=189
MINOR=8
PRODUCT=a5c/21e8/112
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/1/1
UDEV_LOG=6
USEC_INITIALIZED=465479898
```

Running udevadm test on second port (DEVLINK does not exist here as
compared to other device):

udevadm test /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5
    run_command: calling: test
    adm_test: version 175
    This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program,
    specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
    some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

```
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/00-my-usb-device.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/01-my-usb-device.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-local-rpi.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/40-scratch.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/42-qemu-usb.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-fuse.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-gpsd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-i2c-tools.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-ifplugd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-2.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules' as rules file    
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading
'/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules' as
rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-python-pifacecommon.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-python3-pifacecommon.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-triggerhappy.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/run/udev/rules.d/61-dev-root-link.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules' as rules file
add_rule: IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id', replacing
/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules:13
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/70-udev-acl.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules' as rules file
add_rule: IMPORT found builtin 'path_id', replacing
/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules:23
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-cd-aliases-generator.rules'
as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading
'/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading
'/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/99-input.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules' as rules file
udev_rules_new: rules use 145392 bytes tokens (12116 * 12 bytes),
24358 bytes buffer
udev_rules_new: temporary index used 39920 bytes (1996 * 20 bytes)
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x17a748 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x177258 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5'
udev_device_read_db: device 0x177258 filled with db file data
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x177db8 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x178260 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1786d8 has devpath
'/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x178a28 has devpath '/devices/platform'
udev_rules_apply_to_event: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id'
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-2.rules:11
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR=050d
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR_ENC=050d
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR_ID=050d
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL=0234
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL_ENC=0234
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL_ID=0234
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_REVISION=3298
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_SERIAL=050d_0234
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_BUS=usb
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:090001:090002:
udev_rules_apply_to_event: MODE 0664 /lib/udev/rules.d/91-    permissions.rules:36
udev_event_execute_rules: no node name set, will use kernel supplied
name 'bus/usb/001/006'
udev_node_add: creating device node '/dev/bus/usb/001/006',
devnum=189:5, mode=01664, uid=0, gid=0
udev_node_mknod: preserve file '/dev/bus/usb/001/006', because it has
correct dev_t
udev_node_mknod: preserve permissions /dev/bus/usb/001/006, 021664, uid=0,     gid=0
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/189:5' to
'../bus/usb/001/006'
udev_device_update_db: unable to create temporary db file
'/run/udev/data/c189:5.tmp': Permission denied
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/006
DEVNUM=006
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=0234
ID_MODEL_ENC=0234
ID_MODEL_ID=0234
ID_REVISION=3298
ID_SERIAL=050d_0234
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:090001:090002:
ID_VENDOR=050d
ID_VENDOR_ENC=050d
ID_VENDOR_ID=050d
MAJOR=189
MINOR=5
PRODUCT=50d/234/3298
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=9/0/2
UDEV_LOG=6
USEC_INITIALIZED=200440100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel was required. The 2 BT adapters are hooked into a 4-port hub. Once I specified the Kernel in each of the 2 rules, everything worked.

Product and serial were also used to distinguish between the 2 devices (product probably not as necessary since it matches the other BT device, but serial definitely required).